# EE3 Remove Template Group

Tags: templates, ee3, template-manager

I am trying to clean up my templates after an upgrade from EE2 to EE3. Everything I delete / remove keeps reappearing on next log-in. This includes some entire Template Groups and some individual templates in other groups. How do I remove them form the system permanently?

Thanks for any help
-A

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have "Save Templates as Files" turned on but the system may not have permissions to delete the files. So when you delete the template, it is cleared out of the database, but since the templates (may not) have the correct file permissions it can’t delete the files. Therefore when you load the control panel again, the templates are recreated.

It’s very permissive, but just to test, you might try setting your template file folder and all contents inside to 777.

Comment: It is related to permissions somehow. But unfortunately its more than that. I set the permissions to 777 for everything in the templates folder and everything was resolved for a few hours but the issue has since returned. Templates I try to remove keep re-appearing and when they do the permissions on the server also change to 666. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m afraid I’ve never run into this specific problem when permissions were set right. Hopefully someone has and can provide an answer. If not, I would suggest getting in contact with EllisLab support. They’re really good. If you have never used their support before, I believe they have a free period. https://ellislab.com/support